# How to mount a potentially corrupted multi-device btrfs filesystem?

Tags: mount, data-recovery, btrfs, live-usb

My old computer (which I used as a network server) just boots to an initramfs shell. Now I'm trying to recover what I can.

Setup: 250GB internal hard drive and an external 4TB USB hard drive. Both were formatted as btrfs and were mounted as a combined filesystem (so it showed up as 4.25TB). I'm not certain on the last part, it's been a while.

I plugged the USB hard drive into my other computer, and tried mounting with ro, recovery, and degraded. None worked. Then I ran `btrfs device scan` and `btrfs filesystem show`. Here's the output:

```
warning, device 1 is missing
warning, device 1 is missing
bytenr mismatch, want=21004288, have=0
ERROR: cannot read chunk root
Label: 'fedora'  uuid: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        Total devices 2 FS bytes used 2.38TiB
        devid    2 size 3.64TiB used 2.48TiB path /dev/sda
        *** Some devices missing
```

After that I tried running a live USB from the old computer. Now the btrfs commands don't say a device is missing, but when I try to mount it still gives me an error. The error I got on both computers was: `mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.` When I checked dmesg on the old computer, the error message was: `parent transid verify failed on ??????? wanted ?????? found ??????`. I have *not* run `btrfs check` yet.

**How can I safely mount one or both devices (the internal and external hard drives) so I can start copying files to a backup?** Any help is greatly appreciated. Sorry if this is a little complicated.

**Edit**: When I run `btrfs restore /dev/sdc /mnt` it mounts the root, but the home directory is missing, which is where most of the storage was.